# Caption with fixed text but without number

Tags: captions

With the package `caption` I can change the label for my caption,

```
\captionsetup[table]{name=Source}
```

But this keeps numbering - which is not what I'm looking for. If I try `labelformat=empty` or `\caption*` then it won't display the name.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[font=small, format=hang]{caption}

\captionsetup[table]{name=Source}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
            1               &               2
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{test}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

How to have a fixed label without numbering?

Comment: All of them - since I want to use the `captionsetup` (or similar). The above is just a MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own `labelformat` with `\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat`. In its argument `#1` stands for the label, and `#2` for the number, so the standard definition is more or less

```
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{simple}{#1~#2}
```

(This is a white lie: there is in fact a test whether `#1` is empty.) You can thus define your own `labelformat` which prints only the label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[font=small, format=hang]{caption}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{unnumbered}{#1}
\captionsetup[table]{name=Source,labelformat=unnumbered}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
            1  &  2
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{test}
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]